# Why are these two series identical?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone please show/explain to me explicitly why this is true (from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson%27s_lamp)):

$S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots$

The series can be rearranged as:

$S = 1 - (1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots)$

I know this should be obvious, but I'm blaming the flu.

Comment: Although it is not wrong to consider these *series* as sequences (of partial sums), the crux of the justification is to focus on what those partial sums are (when "written out").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A series is characterised by its sequence of partial sums. The two series have the same sequence of partial sums, if we look at a suitable tail. This means either both converge or both diverge, and if they converge, they do so to the same limit.

The first has $1,1-1,1-1+1,1-1+1-1,\ldots$ for partial sums while the second has $1-1,1-(1-1)=1-1+1,1-(1-1+1)=1-1+1-1,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer explains why the sums are formally identical. I'd like to explain why such manipulations with **divergent** series make sense at all. Consider the following sum for $x<1$:

$S(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+...$

This is a familiar geometric series that sums up to $1\over{1+x}$. Now take the limit $x\to 1$ and you get your limit value $S(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Incidentally, notice that $S(x)=1-xS(x)$ for the same reasons the other's explained. One can derive $S(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ from that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $-1$:
$$
a-b+c=a-(b-c)
$$

Answer (score 0):

1 + 1(-1 + 1 + -1 + 1 + -1...)
= 1 + -1 * (1 + 1 + -1 + 1 + -1...)

negative one times a sum of numbers surround by a parenthesis flips the signs

-(x+y) =-1 * (x+ y) = (-x + -y)

Comment: The problem here is to show such a manipulation makes sense and holds correctly for *series* per se, regardless of convergence or divergence.  A more formal approach is appropriate.